# Assert for empty content in 200 Http Response

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

I have a simple Web Api method which returns a list. I decided as a general project rule, that if the list is empty for a particular userId, we return an **Ok()** method with empty content. 
My web api method looks like following:

```
[Route("")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetPersonalList()
{
    var result = _facade.Get(_userContext.Get());
    if (result == null)
        return Ok(); //here is the point

    return Ok(new PersonalExpensesReportViewModel(result));
}
```

Trying to make a 100% of coverage of this method, I wanted to test the scenario that I mentioned, but I could not achieve how to write the assert for the empty content.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetPersonalList_NoContent_Ok()
{
    //Arrange
    _facade.Setup(x => x.Get(_userContext.Object.GetPersonnelNumber(), null)).Returns((PersonalExpensesReport)null);

    //Act
    var result = _controller.GetPersonalList();

    //Assert
    var negociatedResult = result as OkResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    // ?? I want something like Assert.IsNull(negociatedResult.Content)
}
```

Being that I don't have a certain type to make **result as OkNegotiatedContentResult** which expects T type to be instantiated, I thought about cast as OkResult, but *I don't have the 'Content' property in this class*.

Does someone know how to proceed in this cases?

Comment: Why do you not want to use `204 No Content` for empty list?

Comment: Because UI developers have defined it this way :(
I know about that solution and in that case, the unit tests makes simpler, but I can't apply it.

Comment: Ok, did U try `OkNegotiatedContentResult`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use [`OkNegotiatedContentResult<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn308866(v=vs.118).aspx) like:

```
var result = _controller.GetPersonalList();
var response = result as OkNegotiatedContentResult<PersonalExpensesReportViewModel>;   
Assert.IsNotNull(response);
var content = response.Content;
Assert.AreEqual(5, content.Count());
```

Comment: This not solves the problem, because, as I said, my Web Api is returning an empty value and not a PersonalExpensesReportViewModel, so in this case I get the response as 'null' value, being that the compiler cannot cast to this class. I mean, I can't get the instance of OkNegocitatedContentResult.

Comment: To be clearer, if my content is empty, is not correct to use PersonalExpensesReportViewModel as T for OkNegociatedContentResult, do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetPersonalList_NoContent_Ok()
    {

    var serviceresponse = new yourresponseobject<yourmodel>{
    Message = "what ever response";
    Data = null;

    };

    var service = new Mock<youserviceInterface>(MockBehavior.Strict);
                service.Setup(x => x.GetPersonalList()(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(serviceResponse); /// for number of parameters in controller method, add It.IsAny<string>() 
        //Arrange
        _facade.Setup(x => x.Get(_userContext.Object.GetPersonnelNumber(), null)).Returns((PersonalExpensesReport)null);

        //Act
        var result = _controller.GetPersonalList();

        //Assert
        var negociatedResult = result as Object;
        Assert.IsNotNull(result.value);
Assert.AreEqual(200,result.negociatedResult.statuscode);


    }
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile.